Why is Chrome web-security blocking my first party cookie?
I'm trying to go from a monolith hosting my api server and react SPA to seperate hosting options (on the same domain, just different subdomains).
I have my frontend hosted on app.domain.com and backend on api.domain.com (for example).
My server's Set-Cookie header is constructed as follows:
Set-Cookie: cookieName=value; Path=/; Secure; HttpOnly; Domain=.domain.com; SameSite=None
The API response is successful and the cookie is recoginized in the Chrome network tab (Click the request in the net network tab, then click cookie tab and I see it nicely parsed out).
However, the cookie is not stored in the application tab (cookie storage) and is not sent on subsequent API requests by the browser fetch API.  This results in my react SPA getting 401s on all subsequent API requests due to lack of session.
Furthermore, no console warnings are reporting blocked or invalid cookies... HOWEVER, if I start chrome with the following, the cookie is stored without issue and the React SPA can aquire a session token:
open -n -a /Applications/Google\ Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google\ Chrome --args --user-data-dir="/tmp/chrome_dev_test" --disable-web-security

This suggests it's security related... however I fail to see how.  These are not 3rd party cookies as the domains are the same (just different subdomains).  HTTPS traffic is used per the secure cookie requirement... AND I'm setting the cookies domain with a proceeding '.' to indicate my intent for shared access across sub-domains.
I'm testing with Chrome Version 124.0.6367.91 (Official Build) (64-bit)
*Please note: I'm using "domain" for example purposes only - in practice I'm using a real domain.  It should also be noted that all API traffic is over HTTPS.
I've tried no SameSite attribute on the cookie.  I've tried adjusting my cookie settings to allow 3rd party cookies (no difference).  I've tried both Firefox and Chrome with fresh sessions (ingonito) and the cookie is still quitely ignored.
I would expect, since my cookie is being set by a server with the same domain (just different sub-domain) that it would be considered 1st party and be sent with each request.
The HttpOnly cookie attribute is also intentional; I don't want the session token to be accessible to JS (for XSS protection); I just want it to be sent with each request to my backend at api.domain.com.  The fact that my server is setting to cookie domain as .domain.com (note the proceeding dot) should make the cookie applicable to all sub-domains.,

What is your real domain name? Whether a cookie is stored may depend on that, see this answer. And is only the api.domain.com traffic via HTTPS, or also the app.domain.com traffic?

Thanks for the reply @HeikoTheißen!  In actuality, my domains are appjohn.myrepchat.com for the react SPA, and john.myrepchat.com for the API backend.  The cookie domain is set as .myrepchat.com.
As for the traffic via the react SPA, this should be locked down to HTTPS as well per my Cloudfront CDN settings (route HTTP to HTTPS).

This is not a public domain, so the answer linked above may be relevant. If your browser address bar shows http://appjohn.myrepchat.com, the answer below may also be relevant.

If a page loaded over HTTP makes an HTTPS request, this is considered a cross-site request even if both requests use a common superdomain. This is because the schema (http: or https:) is considered when determining the site.
As a consequence, browsers may block cookies that are received with the response to that cross-site request because they are third-party cookies. This is either because of a browser setting or because of browser vendors' attempts to block third-party cookies.
You can verify this by visiting http://httpbin.org/html, opening a browser console and executing
fetch("https://httpbin.org/response-headers?Set-Cookie=a=b;Secure;SameSite=None;HttpOnly",
  {credentials: "include"})

